# MySQL Outer Join 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, outer-join

I have 3 sql tables and I want to make 1 table in html

The tables are:

```
Norm (norm_id, name, description, cluster_cluster_id, orden_orden_id)
Cluster (cluster_id, cluster_name)
Orden (orden_id, orden_name)
```

The table must contain:

`norm_id` - `norm_name` - `norm` - `description` - `cluster_name` - `orden_name`

I think i need to do this with a left outer join?

And how to show it in a table?

Right now i have

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['norm_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['norm_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cluster_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['orden_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: you can use left join  ..

Comment: lol LEFT JOIN will do.. join cluster and orden to norm on the related IDs. `SELECT N.col1,N.col2,etc FROM Norm N LEFT JOIN Cluster C ON N.cluster_cluster_id = C.cluster_id LEFT JOIN Orden O ON N.orden_orden_id = O.orden_id` <= figure that out and put the column names in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can make left outer join like, `SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name1 LEFT JOIN table-name2 
    ON column-name1 = column-name2
 WHERE condition`

Comment: should be `...ON Table1.column_name = Table2.column_name`. Also correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think dash (-) is a valid character for naming columns.

Comment: FYI, No you are wrong. You can create column names like this depending on the db language you're using. Surely that's not a good convention but that's just an example to make things more clear.